# Versioning in Python

Tags: python3, versions

I'm just starting to learn python. For this I want to install the latest version on Ubuntu 18.04.
I have accessed the page https://www.python.org/downloads/.

Python 3.8.3 should be the current verison, right? I entered the following commands and expected phyton 3.8 to be installed on my computer.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install python3.8
```

Unfortunately, this is not the case. At least this request shows me a different version number.

```bsh
python3
Python 3.6.9 (default, Apr 18 2020, 01:56:04) 
[GCC 8.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

Maybe I'm not reading it right?

What do the individual numbers mean and why can't I see 3.8 anywhere?

Comment: As for the individual numbers, you have Python version 3.6.9 built on Apr 18 2020, at 01:56:04 using [GCC 8.4.0](https://gcc.gnu.org/).

Comment: What does running `python3.8` in place of `python3` give you?

Comment: fwiw, 18.04 (bionic) should have python 3.8 available ( https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/python/python3.8 ). But since you may also have python 3.6, 3.7 installed, you'll have to invoke it explicitly via `python3.8`

Comment: Running python3.8 shows me this:

Python 3.8.0 (default, Oct 28 2019, 16:14:01) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. With this informations it is clear to me :)

Comment: I am not sure this is quite the same as https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software. Here 3.8 was explicitly requested and was in the repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu does not distribute the latest packages, they distribute packages that have been tested and known to work together. See [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software) for details.

You have specifically requested that `python3.8` be installed, but incase some packages rely on the older `python3` being installed `python3` will still default to python 3.6.9. To specify that you really want to run python 3.8 run `python3.8` on the command line in place of `python3`.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. With this informations it is clear to me :)